# How to make a loop "continue" only once in C++?

Tags: c++, calculator

I'm currently working on a calculator and am needing to do something that we haven't been taught. Before i discuss what it is, i will post the code below:

SOLVED

```
int num1;
int num2;
char choice;
int answer;
char choice2;
bool MoveOn;
bool ActiveAnswer;

//  get first number

cout << "Enter your first number" << endl;

cin >> num1;

//  get an operator
//      is it valid?  if not, get another operator
while (MoveOn = true)
{
    cout << "What would you like to do? +, -, *, or / ?" << endl;

    //cout << "Press C to clear and start over or X to close the program" << endl;

    cin >> choice;


    if (choice == '+')
    {
        cout << "Enter your second number" << endl;        
        cin >> num2;        
        answer = num1 + num2;        
        cout << "The answer is: " << answer << endl;        

        MoveOn = true;        
        num1 = answer;
        cout << "Enter your second number" << endl;
        cin >> num2;
        answer = num1 + num2;
        cout << "The answer is: " << answer << endl;
    }
}
```

What I'm needing to do is get the first number, the operator, print out the answer, move back and ask for an operator again, use the previous answer as the first number, get a second number, print the answer again. So most of what i need works. It took me a while to figure out how to get it to use the previous answer as the first number again, but then came another problem. After it prints out the first answer, it goes straight to asking for the second number again instead of letting the user select another operator. What i tried was having a continue statement, but then it will just keep going back to asking for an operator and not let the user do a second problem. I also tried doing two separate if statements instead of just the one you see above, but that doesn't work either. I'm not one that wants someone to necessarily fix this for me. I want to understand what happens and know how it works. If anyone could lend me a hand, i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you ask for the second number twice inside the `if` block?

Comment: If you want to go back to asking for the first number, you need an outer loop. Use `break` to get out of the inner loop, or set `MoveOn` to `false`, and then the outer loop will restart.

Comment: **Be careful**: You have written `while(MoveOn = true)` instead of `while(MoveOn == true)`. The first is an infinite loop, cos its really an asigment (`MoveOn` is set to `true`) and the while loop is getting the result of that assigment (A `true` value).  Also, avoid comparisons like `boolean == true`, there are redundant: You are using the boolean value of the result of comparing a boolean variable with a boolean value (`true` or `false`). Use the boolean variable directly: `while( MoveOn )`.

Comment: If i change the beginning of the while to while(MoveOn == true), then it throws an error that the variable is being used without being initialized. If i don't set it = to true, then it doesn't work.

Comment: wait I write you the code

Comment: So initialize the variable before using it, then. Also, you never **ever** set `MoveOn` to `false`. When exactly do you want to get out of the loop?

Comment: @user2778151 then, initialize it before the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look closely at your code and step through what it does.

The flow right now looks like this:

```
Ask for a number (num1)

(start_loop):

Ask for an operator
Ask for a second number (num2)
Calculate the answer (answer = num1 + num2)
Print the answer

**Ask for a second number (num2)**
Calculate the answer (answer = num1 + num2)
Print the answer

(go back to start_loop)
```

You're asking for a second  number twice which is why you're not being prompted for an operator again. There's no need to ask twice in the same loop, because the computer will loop back and repeat the first request you typed in anyway.

The key is to just use answer as num1.

```
(start_loop):

Ask for an operator
Ask for a second number (num2)
Calculate the answer (answer = num1 + num2)
Print the answer
Set the new first number to be the answer (num1 = answer)

(go back to start_loop)
```

If you continued where you were going with the second request, you'd need to also add a request for the next operator, and repeat the entire block all over again. That's what loops are meant to do - repeat your block of code, so if you start seeing duplicated code in a loop it should be a red flag that you're doing it wrong.

Let the loop repeat the code for you. Your job is to figure out how to best write the block of code that gets repeated, and when the loop should be terminated.

Comment: The reason i ask for the second number twice is because after it's supposed to grab the next operator (after it does the first answer), it grabs a new second number, so i can't use the original one. The flow should be as follows:

get first number
get operator
get second number
print answer
loop back and ask for a new operator
use original answer as the first number
ask for a new second number
print the new answer

The above is what i need it to do. This is why the second number is there twice, it's because i need a NEW one and not the original. If it's taken out, it won't work.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense now. I've edited my answer to have it do what you want. The key part is that you shouldn't be duplicating code inside a loop - that's what loops are for anyway.

Comment: Here is what I came up with that seems to work.

`
MoveOn = true;
 while (MoveOn)
  {
  cout << "What would you like to do? +, -, *, or / ?" << endl;
  
//cout << "Press C to clear and start over or X to close the program" << endl;

cin >> choice;
  

  if (choice == '+') 
   {
    cout << "Enter your second number" << endl;

     cin >> num2;

      answer = num1 + num2;
 
       cout << "The answer is: " << answer << endl;

        num1 = answer;
   
         continue;
       
        
    
   }
  }
`

Comment: Alright i can't get the code to look proper on this reply box and it won't let me edit my last comment... So I'll just link a screenshot of it. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/liuftps7adj1evk/Code.png minutes

Comment: I can't see the dropbox link, presumably because it's been blocked, but the code looks fine. There's no need for the continue statement though.

Comment: The continue doesn't exist there now, but i do have it in this next chunk of code. Hasan posted something i needed, but i had to modify it for how i needed it to function

char QuitClear;
   cout << "Press q to quit, c to clear, or any other key to continue" << endl;
   cin >> QuitClear;
   if (QuitClear == 'q')
    MoveOn = false;
   else
    if (QuitClear == 'Q')
     MoveOn = false;
    else 
     if (QuitClear == 'c')
      {
      cout << "Enter your first number" << endl;
       cin >> num1;
      }
    else
     continue;

All that came right after the last chunk of code i posted above.

Comment: So far everything is working 100% correctly so i greatly appreciate the help and advice i have received from everyone here. :)

Answer (score 0):

- If you are trying to terminate your program, This is how you should do it. I think you got it right on your last comment, however you need to understand how the while loop and for loop works. They work continuously unless you tell it to stop, you need to know how to start the loop running and how to terminate it.
- Basically without a FALSE statement your while loop will not terminate, and if you input or enter any statement that would alter the TRUE statement, then it will stop.
- The while loop start running from the FIRST line within its scope and run until the LAST line within its scope. Before starting all over again from the FIRST line to the LAST line and will continue to loop again and again unless otherwise instructed to terminate.
- Therefore,you do not need to start writing your code again when you are trying to terminate your program.
- So this is how you should terminate the program;

  ```
     // Declare this variable on top of the function
     char terminate = 'W';

     // This will be placed at the bottom of your function
     cout << "Enter X to close the program, Otherwise Enter any key to continue" << endl;
     // The program has to be terminated by the user, Enter X to terminate
     // Otherwise, Enter any key to continue.
     cin >> terminate;
     if(terminate == 'X' || terminate == 'x')
     MoveOn = false;
     // Remember that char is case sensitive, X is different from x
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did a lot of restructuring to the code last night and converted almost all of the if statements into a switch. For termination, i have it set up like so:

cout << "What would you like to do? +, -, *, or / ?" << endl;
   cout << "Press X to quit, C to clear, or just continue" << endl;
   cin >> Choice;
   switch (Choice)
    {
    case 'X':
    case 'x':
     MoveOn = false;
     break;

There is more code that follows, but that's just what i have for closing the program.